# Having trouble calculating Home Range area

Tags: r, range, adehabitathr

I am having a lot of trouble in R calculating the area of home range of an animal.  I thought once I produced a home range (if I've done it correctly) calculating the area would be easy, but no

I've pasted some of the code I've been trying.  I wonder would anyone have any insight?

```
# Load package

    library(adehabitat)

#Load file Frodo

    dd <- read.csv(file.choose(), header = T)

# Plot the home range

    xy <- dd[,c("X","Y")]
    id <- dd[,"name"]
    hr<- mcp(xy,id,percent=95)
    plot(hr)
    points(xy[xy$id=="frodo",])

#Great. Home range produced.  Now calculate area

    area <- mcp.area(xy, id,percent = 95),

# Result 2.287789e-09 Ha.  Way to small.  Maybe it doesnt like Lat / Long.  

# Will try and convert coordinates  into M or Km

# Load map project

    library(mapproj)

    x<-mapproject(t$X,t$Y,projection="mercator")

# Its converted it to something but its not M's  or Km's.  
# I'll try and run it anyway

    xy <- x[,c("X","Y")]

# incorrect number of dimensions

# Ill try Project 4
library(proj4)

    xy <- dd[,c("X","Y")]
    tr <- ptransform(xy/180*pi, '+proj=latlong +ellps=sphere',
                 '+proj=merc +ellps=sphere')
    View(tr)

# There seems to be a Z column filled with 0's. 
# It that going to affect anything? 
# Let's look at the data
    plot(tr)

# Looks good, Lets try and create a home range

    xy <- tr[,c("x","y")]
#  'incorrect number of dimensions'
```

No idea what the problem is.  Don't know if I'm on the right track or doing something completely wrong

Comment: run `dim(x)` to see what the dimensionality of your object actually is.

Comment: It's hard to help without having your data in hand, but I think you're right that this is a matter of having the wrong projection. Should this critter of yours have home ranges of ~ 10-30 hectares?

Comment: Also, a few related suggestions: (1) you should start using **adehabitatHR** (as you are advised by the now-abandoned **adehabitat** each time you launch it); (2) you need to familiarize yourself with the **sp** package, which supplies R's defacto standard representations of spatial objects, and will make it easy for you to reproject polygons, find areas, and a hundred other basic spatial operations. (At a quick glance it looks like **adehabitatHR** has rewritten much of its code to use **sp**'s `Spatial**` classes rather than its own home-rolled versions, and that's a very good thing!)

Comment: This questions mixes up issues of adehabitat* (which doesn't support longlat data), and projections in general. mapproj assumes the unit sphere, you can scale them up but I'd just use rgdal instead, and something better than Mercator. If you just need a local projection for a small area +proj=laea is hard to beat, use arguments +lon_0 and +lat_0 to centre it on your area.

Answer (score 2):

In order to calculate area you need your points in a projected coordinate systems (area in long/lat would just be units of degree). The type of projection you use is going to have a big effect on the resulting area. For instance the Mercator projection distorts area away from the Equator -- you might want to look into the best equal-area projection for your location. I am going to answer the programming part of your question, once you find the right projections to use you can substitute them in.

```
require(sp)
require(rgdal)
orig.points <- dd[,c("X","Y")]

# geographic coordinate system of your points
c1 <- CRS("+proj=latlong +ellps=sphere") 

# define as SpatialPoints
p1 <- SpatialPoints(orig.points, proj4string=c1) 

# define projected coordinate system of your choice, I am using the one you 
# defined above, but see:     
# http://www.remotesensing.org/geotiff/proj_list/mercator_1sp.html
# to make sure your definition of the mercator projection is appropriate
c2 <- CRS("+proj=merc ellps=sphere")

p2 <- spTransform(p1, c2) # project points
# convert to Polygon (this automatically computes the area as an attribute)
poly <- Polygon(p2)
poly@area #will print out the area
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  I understand now getting my data in the correct format is what I need to do.  I ran your code ge and got the error message "Error in CRS("+proj=latlong +ellps=sphere") : 
  northings must follow eastings: +proj=latlong +ellps=sphere" when it ran c1 <- ....

Comment: There is a typo in the answer above, the c1 line should be: c1 <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=sphere")     that is 'longlat' not 'latlong'. I tried to edit the answer but edit was rejected for unknown reason.